# DataBind() System.Web.HttpException ID not found in datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I'm making a webform using visual studio

I have a grid in the .aspx and i'm going to fill it in the backend page using c#

here is the code in the .aspx

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvusers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 

            <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="First Name" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Name" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone Number" HeaderText="Phone Number" />




            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the function that is supposed to fill it ( aspx.cs) :

```
void GridFill() {
            using (MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter sqlda = new MySqlDataAdapter("userviewall", sqlCon);
                sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                sqlda.Fill(dtbl);
                gvusers.DataSource = dtbl;
                gvusers.DataBind();
            }
```

I cannot detect the source of this exception so i can fix it.

Stack trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): لم يتم العثور على حقل أو خاصية بالاسم 'ID' في مصدر البيانات المحدد.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.TryGetSimplePropertyValue(Object dataItem, Object& data) +416
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.GetValue(Control controlContainer) +384
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.OnDataBindField(Object sender, EventArgs e) +147
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +165
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +215
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +36
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +244
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +225
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +36
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +243
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +7051
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +117
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +65
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +208
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +131
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +226
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +140
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +29
   NoufsTask.Index.GridFill() in c:\Users\abdulaziz\Desktop\NoufsTask\NoufsTask\Index.aspx.cs:77
   NoufsTask.Index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\abdulaziz\Desktop\NoufsTask\NoufsTask\Index.aspx.cs:22
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +159
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +165
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +170
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3615
```

Comment: What does `userviewall` return?  The error seems to suggest that the results don't include a column called `ID`.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the contents of the datatable are. Have you debugged this?

Comment: please post the complete exception details with stack trace

Comment: @David it's a query that selects everything in the table

Comment: @Kell like, do you want me to tell you what columns does this database have? it's userid, firstname, lastname, phoneno, udate

Comment: @EhsanSajjad updated the question and added stack trace, check please

Comment: @YaraBinSaif: Looking at what the query returns would certainly be a good step in debugging.

Comment: Your ID field should probably be UserID. Try changing DataField="ID" to DataField="UserID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your proper error message is :

> A field or property with the name 'ID` was not found on the selected data source

### Solution:

You  didn't select the `ID` in the select query(`userviewall` it should be a SQL query) so that error message came. Just select the `ID`(Which columns need to bind in grid) in Your query.

**Important :** 
Not only the ID filed,  You should be return all fields to data bind in grid View. Your select query should be looks like

```
select ID, FirsName, LastName,PhoneNumber from YourTableName // or try select * from YourTableName
```

Also you should provide the column name in `"FirstName"` DataFiled property for the Data grid Bound Filed. And `DataField` property does not accept the `variable` with `space`. So you should provide the `datafield` property be `DataField="FirstName"` instead of `DataField="First Name"` .

Kindly check this forum [site](https://forums.asp.net/t/2094276.aspx?getting%20this%20error%20when%20binding%20datagrid)

Comment: This solved everything I get no error nor exception now thank you very much